# How to have functions in an object array with ngFor that can be clicked

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an example at [StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mx9ujo)

Trying to have unique functions per list item where the function can then be clicked when `ngFor` list has been rendered.

I've found that the functions fire instantly and cannot be clicked.

```
public actions = [
    {
      label: 'Method1',
      func: this.goTo('method1')
    },
    {
      label: 'Method2',
      func: this.goTo('method2')
    },
    {
      label: 'Return method invocation',
      func: this.clickButton()
    },
  ];

   goTo(val) {
        console.log(val);
   }
   clickButton() {
        console.log('button clicked');
   }


<ng-container *ngFor="let action of actions">
  <button (click)="action.func">{{ action.label }}</button>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: You should wrap the click function with an anonymous function in the template.

Comment: @callback would you share an example for the example above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make 2 changes to your code:

1. In HTML file change the click function to execute func property:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let action of actions">
  <button (click)="action.func()">{{ action.label }}</button>
</ng-container>
```

2. change the `func` property in your model to be a function:

```
{
  label: 'Method1',
  func: () => this.goTo('method1')
}
```

See this [Forked StackBlitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v4dgll) with the solution.